# File Storage Gadget vs Mass Storage gadget

Tags: linux, embedded, usb, usb-mass-storage

On embedded device I would like to use USB Gadget - Mass Storage. I found two options in menu, but they are not strictly defined.

In Mass Storage section:

```
This is heavily based on File-backed Storage Gadget and in most
cases you will want to use FSG instead. This gadget is mostly
here to test the functionality of the Mass Storage Function
which may be used with composite framework.
If unsure, consider File-backed Storage Gadget.
```

Could someone write more details ?

Is FSG focused on embedded world ?

Answer (score 2):

Mass storage gadget is an improved version of file storage gadget. According to official documentation:

`File Storage Gadget has been removed in Linux 3.8. All users need to transition to the Mass Storage Gadget.`

(from: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt)

The same page also lists difference between modules (not much -- some parameters are named differently/have different format)